# gridview not visible in updatepanel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, updatepanel

I currently have a `GridView` in a pop-up control. The `GridView` is embedded in an `UpdatePanel` and I have the window pop-up showing nothing on it. However, when I debug through it I see that the `GridView` has data in it and it is bound, but I am not noticing any changes. I even tried to call the Update method on the `UpdatePanel`, but received no changes in that either.

Basically what I wish to do is show a blank page up until my data has been loaded in. After the `GridView` has the data bound to it I would like it to be visible. Please find the below code snippet of the current process.

ASPX source:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupItem" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" LoadingPanelImagePosition="Bottom"
    Modal="True" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter"
    EnableAnimation="False" HeaderText="Item Checker" 
    Width="614px">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupCoverageItem" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
            <table style="width: 611px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        Title
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div style="height: 75px; overflow: auto; width: 595px;">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpItems" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTitles" Width="575px" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="90px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <center>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton OnClick="btnSelect_Click" ID="lnk_Select" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("title") %>'
                                                            ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" ToolTip="Choose this record" />
                                                    </center>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="90px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item ID" DataField="item_id" SortExpression="item_id" />
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="title" SortExpression="title" />
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="date" SortExpression="date" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancelTitle" Text="Cancel" CssClass="popupButton"
                            OnClick="btnCancelTitle_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

C# back end:

```
// Bind the data from the returning SQL query and update
            gv.DataSource = npgDat;
            gv.DataBind();
            udpItems.Update();
```

Unfortunately there isn't much more of the C# back-end that I can show since we're using a company specific Query tool that works well in other situations.

Thanks

Comment: paste ur code so we can find problem

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code.

Comment: what do you mean with `Basically what I wish to do is show a blank page up until my data has been loaded in. After the GridView has the data bound to it I would like it to be visible. Please find the below code snippet of the current process.` if your data s not loaded it will automatically show nothing and if you really really want to show a blank page to user and let him/her wait try you can try `Thread.Sleep()` or `TimeSpan` check [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Pretty much I would like to load a page with a cursor animation until my SQL query is able to return results and bind to the GridView. Once the data is bound I would like the GridView to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure an `ASPxPopupControl` supports having an `UpdatePanel` as content? I'd try getting rid of the `UpdatePanel` and see if the `GridView` works as expected then, or try moving the `UpdatePanel` (with the `GridView` still inside it) outside of the `ASPxPopupControl` and see if that works. If the problem is having the `UpdatePanel` inside the `ASPxPopupControl`, then you'll probably have to contact DevExpress for more help, as that would lead me to believe it's a problem with their control.

**Update**
Based on your comment below, you may want to look into [Example: How to show the ASPxLoadingPanel while the content is loading inside the ASPxPopupControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S33971.aspx) over on the DevExpress support forum.

Comment: I've been able to have a GridView load without the UpdatePanel just fine. The only reason I am inserting an UpdatePanel is to visually show that a query is running in the background.

Comment: This pretty much did the job for me. I just need to tweak it a bit to do what I'd like it too. Thanks for the info.

Comment: had this problem and removing the update panel fixed it. thanks